# Facebook API to download info about all friends and download their pictures

Tags: facebook, api

I'm trying create application that is recognizing my firends by facebook pictures that I have access to. I need to have access all my friends picstures that I can see and information about them. I haven't tried yet selenium-webdriver drivers. Facebook app API allowes me to get info only if they install my app. Is there any other way to grab infos with pictures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no other way. Scraping is not allowed on Facebook, you MUST use the API. Access is only available to friends who authorized the App.

For privacy reasons, data of any user who did not authorize your App is none of your business, and you are not allowed to do anything with any data without specific permission of each user.